# Placing footnotes on the inside column

Tags: footnotes, two-column

Packages such as `ftnright` allow the placement of footnotes in the the right column only, when using `twocolumn`. Is there an equivalent to allow the placement of footnotes on the inside column only? (That is to say, looking at a double page spread, in the right column on the left page, and in the left column on the right page.)

I looked on CTAN to see if there were any packages that might help, but couldn't find any; the most promising (initially) was [`fnpos`](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/yafoot/yafoot-man.pdf), but this appears to only manipulate the vertical placement of footnotes.

I don't have an MWE since I am entirely sure how to start going about this.

Comment: I don't think that it would easy. Inserting footnotes *later* is not so difficult, but at least on the right page you want to insert them in a earlier column.